# Paging library DataSource.Factory for multiple data sources android

Tags: android, android-paging

I have multiple data sources. But there is only one DataSourceFactory. So, all sources is sharing one factory. I need one DataSourceFactory per data source.

In my app, I have multiple views with RecyclerViews and hence multiple custom data sources. So, do you end up creating multiple implementations of DataSource.Factory per data source or is there a more generic solution?

**Edited**

I found the solution in my case. In my previous version, I used only one Datasource Factory for all datasources. Now I create Datasource Factory Object whenever calling method from ViewModel like

```
private void initData(String id) {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    factory = new EvaluationDataSourceFactory(compositeDisposable, api, id);

    networkState = Transformations.switchMap(factory.getDataSource(), source -> {
                Timber.d("network status get");
                return source.getNetworkState();
            }
    );

    PagedList.Config pagedListConfig =
            (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                    .setInitialLoadSizeHint(5)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                    .setPageSize(5).build();

    error = Transformations.switchMap(factory.getDataSource(), source -> {
        return source.getError();
    });

    assessments = (new LivePagedListBuilder(factory, pagedListConfig)).setFetchExecutor(executor).build();
}

public void getAssessments(String id) {
    initData(id);
}
```

Then, you can call this method from your activity or fragment like

```
viewModel.getAssessments(id);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I already answered. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123791/paging-library-datasource-factory-for-multiple-data-sources/59270786#59270786)